# Chef daemon running every 30 minutes

Tags: chef-infra

I understand that Chef is pull based in the sense that it detects any changes in the recipes and uses chef client to install the changes.
We use chef to bring up EC2 instances but the chef-client which runs as a daemon every 30 minutes and runs all the recipes again causing unwanted changes to some services.
I would like to know what options are there to change this and run the chef-client on a on demand basis.

Following are the options I have thought of so far,

1. Change the interval time on the chef-client cookbook to very high time so that the daemon does no run often.
2. After the EC2 instance is deployed kill the chef daemon ssh or maybe even a chef-recipe.

Also I believe chef-client has log rotation scheduled on a weekly basis, this will again restart the chef-client. 
Any ideas on how to avoid this pull based behavior ?

Comment: Empty run_list of that node. Let chef-client run every 30 mins doing nothing and "on demand" $knife node your_node edit and update run_list.

Answer (score 10):

First of all:

Your chef recipes should set your node in 1 and the same configuration, no matter how many times chef is run. You also should never restart any service on your own. This behaviour should be notified by the config files, if they are changed. For example:

```
service 'apache2' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end

template '/etc/apache2/httpd.conf' do
  action :create
  [...]
  notifies, :restart, 'service[apache2]' #this notification will launch, only if the file has changed
end
```

You can also disable chef-client daemon, by running `chef-client --once`. This way chef will provision the node and will remove self from cron. Thus in the future it will be run only manually on demand.

But your bigger problem is actually that your chef-client run causes changes to some of your services with every run. You should solve it first.

Comment: Thanks Draco. You are that as to what the bigger problem is and it needs to be solved. But till that gets solved we need to disable the client on EC2 instances. Using the --once option will require a change to all the templates in the recipe ?

Comment: I meant the the cookbook in the previous comment.

Comment: It does not require any change in cookbooks. Just login to your EC2 node and run `sudo chef-client --once`. Or `sudo service chef-client stop`. Or create a recipe that stops the service: `service 'chef-client' { action [:stop, :disable] }`. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I don't understand the `--once` option. chef-client is daemonized with `--daemonize` option, but combining it with `--once` for me is the same as removing them both.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Draco said about fixing the underlying problem, but if you want to stop the chef-client from running every 30 minutes, you should be able to just remove the chef-client::service recipe from your run list. See the [chef-client README](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-client#recipes).

Answer (score 0):

If you're building config files from Chef databags, you will want to sort result from searches as these will *not* be returned in the same order in different runs. If you don't sort results, you will have Apache services which restart too often for no apparent reason.

Make sure your chef-client runs are idempotent with the same data. Can't stress this enough.